# Telegram API send message special character

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to send an URL that contains thespecial character # through Telegram API  post request.
I'm currently use HTML as parse mode.
The message to send is something like:

```
<a href='www.example.com/#/otherparams'>inline link example</a>
```

But when I send message the substring of the URL from the # to the end is automatically deleted.

I try to encode the # with related ASCII code %23 and the message is sent correctly, but the when I click on the link the URL doesn't works. I think there isn't a resolution of %23. If I manually replace the ASCII code in the URL bar of the browser with # works.

I obviously try to escape the char # with backslash, but the problem still persists.

On the docs I can't find nothing.
This is an example of script that I'm using, written in Python.
The problem is only #, if I change the message with an URL that doesn't contain #, the script works.

```
import requests
msg="<a href='www.example.com/#/otherparams'>inline link example</a>"
requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage" + "?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&parseMode=html&text=" + msg)
```

Comment: You are using `parseMode=HTML` which is incorrect. Use `parse_mode=html` instead.

Comment: Yes, I have wrote html in the script, I have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Change `parseMode=HTML` to `parse_mode=HTML` in `requests.post(...` line

Comment: Yes, I m writing the question from the phone. I have done some typo error, but the script work, the problem is the #

Comment: Try to append `http` or `https` within href url

Comment: The code works correctly if I use a link without #. So the problem is this. How escape #?